# Optimal way of handling static page routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have a rails app where I'd like to introduce some static pages. Since my app has both a "public" face and a comprehensive admin backend, I have decided to move my controllers into corresponding subfolders, so app/controllers only contains two subfolders.

Right now, I am creating a policy section with company policies.

I have come up with this solution so far, but it's not working

```
namespace :policy, path: 'politik' do
  get 'miljoe'
  get 'kvalitet'
  get 'kunde'
  get 'personale'
end
```

This creates the following routes:

```
                 policy_miljoe GET    /politik/miljoe(.:format)                      policy#miljoe
               policy_kvalitet GET    /politik/kvalitet(.:format)                    policy#kvalitet
                  policy_kunde GET    /politik/kunde(.:format)                       policy#kunde
              policy_personale GET    /politik/personale(.:format)                   policy#personale
```

Short routes and correct paths. This is all great, except...
It looks in app/controllers for a controller, rather than looking in app/controllers/public. Adding a

```
namespace :policy, path: 'politik', controller: 'public/policy' do
```

is not doing the trick.

My only "solution" so far has been to create a fake resources route pointing to the controller and do additional collection routes like this:

```
resources :policy, path: 'politik', controller: 'public/policy', only: [] do
  collection do
    get 'miljoe'
    get 'kvalitet'
    get 'kunde'
    get 'personale'
  end
end
```

This works, but it

- appends index the url helpers for no apparent reason, so instead of policy_miljoe_path I get miljoe_policy_index_path.
- reads in a strange way, because resources implies restfulness and there's nothing restful about these pages.

How can I best/most elegantly declare these static pages in the router and maintain an url structure that looks different from my directory structure `/politik/kvalitet` in the router, but `/public/policy/kvalitet` in the folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `scope` which solves the problem perfectly:

```
scope module: 'public' do
  namespace :policy, path: 'politik' do
    get 'miljoe'
    get 'kvalitet'
    get 'kunde'
    get 'personale'
  end
end
```

This produces the following helpers, urls and actions.

```
    policy_miljoe GET    /politik/miljoe(.:format)       public/policy#miljoe
  policy_kvalitet GET    /politik/kvalitet(.:format)     public/policy#kvalitet
     policy_kunde GET    /politik/kunde(.:format)        public/policy#kunde
 policy_personale GET    /politik/personale(.:format)    public/policy#personale
```